# Using OR in a IF

Tags: php

Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
if($page->Slug != 'water-filters' || $page->Slug != 'pet-care' || $page->Slug != 'books') {
  //do something 
}
```

Comment: Define *this isn't working* please. Works perfectly for me: http://codepad.org/9tvMPsH7 You have to tell what **you** want to happen.

Comment: What is $page->Slug and what happens actually?

Comment: if i remove everything after || it works, ie only one check.  If i use the OR it wont work...

Comment: what echo $page->Slug outputs?

Comment: $page->Slug this is just the page url

Comment: Andy, you need to put some more effort in trying to explain the problem itself so people can help you. On the plus side it will help you understand the problem better and hopefuly allow you to solve it yourself.

Comment: @Andy: have to tried adding parenthesis, as in `if(($page->Slug != 'water-filters') || (...) || (...))` ?

Comment: Try by adding brackets if(($page->Slug != '...') || (....) || (...)) {

Comment: Could it be you want `AND` ? What does *does not work* mean? Does the code not run or does it not behave like you expect?

Comment: I should have been using && as stated below....thank you everyone for helping!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you mean AND instead of OR because you're using not equals.

By using not equals in the way you are the statement will always be true, if $page->Slug equals 'water-filters' it doesn't equal 'pet-care' and hence the if statement as a whole returns true.

```
if($page->Slug != 'water-filters' && $page->Slug != 'pet-care' && $page->Slug != 'books')
{
    //do something 
}
```

Comment: FIXED!  Thanks mate, got it the wrong way around.  It made sense in my head :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that "do something" is always getting executed?

```
if($page->Slug != 'water-filters' || $page->Slug != 'pet-care' || $page->Slug != 'books') 
{
  //do something 
}
```

For any value of $page->Slug, it will always be not equal to ONE of those three conditions, therefore at least one (technically, at least two) of the statements will always be true. Since you're using an 'OR' as long as one of the three statements is true, the whole thing will be true.

Therefore, this is essentially saying

```
if (true) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$page->Slug is either 'water-filters' or 'pet-care' or 'books'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
== or == or ==
```

or

```
!= and != and !=
```

:-D

Answer (score 0):

> If the Slug is not "water-filters" or is not "pet-care" or is not "books"...

Well, if it's one of those, or any other value, it's by definition not the other two (or not all three). So this condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what the others have said above, which are correct also, try this syntax for readability.

```
if(!in_array($page->Slug, array('water-filters', 'pet-care', 'books')) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats a nice way of doing it.